# How to make Windows HDD bootable

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-8

I had been having trouble booting my Windows 8 PC.

I've tried a few different things but right now,  when I try to boot, it doesn't recognise the HDD as being bootable. (I'm not sure if this is the root of the problem or something I caused while trying to fix)

I have connected it to another PC and all the files seem to be there, so I'm assuming that Windows  (at least the files anyway) is still properly installed.

So is there a way of making the disk bootable without having to reformat / reinstall  Windows? (It came preinstalled on the PC and I doubt I'll be able to find the product key)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HP Pavillion won't boot - stuck on logo with spinning dots](https://superuser.com/questions/1641445/hp-pavillion-wont-boot-stuck-on-logo-with-spinning-dots)

Comment: @Moab not sure how it would,  it doesn't have an answer! In any case,  this question is specifically asking how to make a HD into a bootable HD assuming Windows is already on it.

Comment: Since you are clearly smart enough to take the drive out, I would back it up and reinstall.  You will probably have the option to leave your files intact.  If it was an OEM install then the key is either on the machine (via fancy sticker) or already stored in the firmware and windows wont ask for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately with Windows 8 an awful lot of the techniques for dealing with this sort of problem have been hidden. What I generally do with this is get the Windows 8 install media - can be a USB stick that has been made bootable with Balena Etcher or the like, or a DVD burned from a downloaded ISO - and select Repair This Windows Installation when it reaches that point. You won't need the key; starting with Windows 8 it would actually put the key in storage in BIOS. (It does ask for it, but you can just leave that blank.) But you will need to give it a net connection at some point.

Comment: It seems this did the trick. Having the Windows Install media plugged in allowed me into the system repair, and I was given the choice of booting from USB - when I did, my system magically fixed itself! I didn't have to reinstall Windows. I will post the complete process I followed below for posterity.